# Disable/Escape TortoiseSVN Commit Dialog Markup

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, markup

In the commit dialog, Tortoise provides some simple automatic markup: underscores for underlined text, asterisks for bold, and caret for italics. This is all well and good, but I do a lot of work in Python, and any time I try to write a log message that mentions a function or method with two or more underscores in it (e.g. `__init__`, or `do_a_thing`), I get unwanted underlines when I really just want those underscores.

The TortoiseSVN site lists this as a [feature](http://tortoisesvn.net/features.html#), but I would love to be able to turn it off. I haven't found any way to "escape" the markup characters, and there doesn't appear to be any setting to ignore them. Is there any way to disable this markup (perhaps some arcane settings file?), or should I just give up on being able to use the Tortoise commit dialog, and always go directly through the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Settings, Advanced there should be an option called *StyleCommitMessages* that if you set to false will disable this behavior.

It's documented in the [Tortoise SVN Documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html).